# Google Sheets — Strange points appearing on graph that aren't part of the data set (date x axis)

Tags: google-sheets, graph, charts, dataset, point

One of my college classes is deciding on a song to sing at the end of the year (long story), and I'm playing around with the response data for fun.

I did a basic pie chart and bar graph, then I had the idea to monitor the amount of votes each song got as a function of time, so you can see a sort of timeline for the whole voting period. I have the date as the X axis and the number of votes as the Y axis. It works perfectly fine when the results are aggregated, or when I treat the dates as text, but as soon as I unclick "aggregate", so I can show the actual timeline with proportional gaps for gaps in responses, these weird points appear at 18:47:43, where they go *back down*, even though that's nowhere in my dataset.

[image: An image of a line graph, showing this strange behaviour]
[image: An image of a scatterplot with these points, with arrows drawn on to point to them]
[image: An image of the dataset, where no entries for those points exist]

I'm completely lost, I have looked where I can but I genuinely have no idea why these are showing up. Is this a known bug? Did I set something up wrong? [Here's the link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEEp3b-pGQjPxj9GVo-f-4zBcCTJKYlBL2yRwD6gIOs/edit?usp=sharing), in case you can find something I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a bug in charts, but I think the issue is to do with the formatting of the data on the x-axis, being a date/time number.

In cell `'Binary Conversion'!A2` you have `=Responses!A2`

If these were changed to `=text(Responses!A2,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`, then the extra dots disappear from sheet 'Timeline De-Aggregated Scatter Plot (WIP)' and it looks like this.

I don't use scatter charts so I don't know if this is what you're looking to visualise? I've enable the 'data lables' to show the values on 'All Star'.

[image]

Also, your sheet is quite slow to process. It might be because you have lots of formula in lots of individual cells.

You could really simplify things with some of the other Sheet functions. In particular, `ARRAYFORMULA` to calculate from a cell downwards without needing to drag the formulas down.

You could even simplify how you get the data from 'Responses' sheet and just display the songs in the text.

Try this on a new sheet called `FilteredData`:

`={Responses!A:A,arrayformula(regexreplace(iferror(trim(split(regexreplace(Responses!B1:B,"(\ \(https:\/\/youtu.be\/)([\w\-]){11}\)(\,\ )*",","),",")),),"\ by\ .*",""))}`

It uses:

`REGEXREPLACE` to find `(https://youtu.be/***********),`  and replace with `,`.

`SPLIT` to then split the data into new columns by `,`.

`TRIM` to remove any spaces either side of the results.

`IFERROR` to ignore results where the `REGEXREPLACE` doesn't find find `(https://youtu.be/***********)`.

Another `REGEXREPLACE` to remove  `by ******`.

`ARRAYFORMULA` to calculate down the sheet.

You could then get an automatic count of songs on a new sheet using somthing like this in cell A1 on another new sheet:

`={query(UNIQUE({flatten(FilteredData!B2:X)}),"Where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0),ARRAYFORMULA(countif(FilteredData!A:Z,query(UNIQUE({flatten(FilteredData!B2:X)}),"Where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0)))}`

You could also generate a dynamic list of songs in a row using this formula in cell B1 on another new sheet:

`=transpose(query(UNIQUE({flatten(FilteredData!B2:X)}),"Where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0))`

Cell A1 would be:

`={Responses!A:A}`

Then something else to fill in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll definitely look into those optimizations! Unfortunately, that doesn't really help my problem. Having them evenly spaced like that, either through treating the dates like text or through toggling the "aggregate" option, is what I've done with the 'Timeline' sheet, what I'm trying to do now is actually have the graph proportional to the time between changes, meaning it has to stay as a number.